# How to do proper testing in Weka and how to get desired results ?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, svm, prediction, neural-network

I am currently working over a application of ANN, SVM and Linear Regression methods for prediction of fruit yield of a region based on meteorological factors (13 factors )
Total data set is: 36

While Implementing those methods on WEKA I am getting BAD results:
Like in the case of MultilayerPreceptron my results are :
(i divided the dataset with 28 for training and 8 for test )
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a -G -R
Relation:     apr6_data
Instances:    28
Attributes:   15

Time taken to build model: 3.69 seconds

=== Predictions on test set ===

inst#     actual  predicted      error
     1      2.551      2.36      -0.191 
     2      2.126      3.079      0.953 
     3      2.6        1.319     -1.281 
     4      1.901      3.539      1.638 
     5      2.146      3.635      1.489 
     6      2.533      2.917      0.384 
     7      2.54       2.744      0.204 
     8      2.82       3.473      0.653

=== Evaluation on test set ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                 -0.4415
Mean absolute error                      0.8493
Root mean squared error                  1.0065
Relative absolute error                144.2248 %
Root relative squared error            153.5097 %
Total Number of Instances                8

In case of SVM for regression :
 inst#     actual  predicted      error
     1      2.551      2.538     -0.013 
     2      2.126      2.568      0.442 
     3      2.6        2.335     -0.265 
     4      1.901      2.556      0.655 
     5      2.146      2.632      0.486 
     6      2.533      2.24      -0.293 
     7      2.54       2.766      0.226 
     8      2.82       3.175      0.355

=== Evaluation on test set ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.2888
Mean absolute error                      0.3417
Root mean squared error                  0.3862
Relative absolute error                 58.0331 %
Root relative squared error             58.9028 %
Total Number of Instances                8

What can be the possible error in my application ? Please let me know ! 
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to give us some more information. What are the attributes that you are using (type, range)? What exactly are you trying to predict? Also, in general you'll need a dataset much larger than 36 to achieve good results.

Comment: I am basically using year(1),annual_rainfall(1), max_temperature(4),min_temperature(4),solar_radiation(4). Max_temperature,min_temperature and solar radiations are each 4 factors as I am considering only fruit season... i.e. nov-dec, dec-jan, jan-feb, feb-mar. So each becomes a factor. All are numeric data with range as follows:

Comment: year: 1973-74 to 2008-2009 annual rainfall: 365mm to 1617mm radiation around 11 to 20 ... max and min temperature in degrees centigrade. yield is in tons/hectare.

Comment: Do I need to normalize the data ? I guess it is being done by WEKA classifiers.

Comment: You might have better luck with discretising the prediction e.g. into low/medium/high yield.

Comment: The values are in the range min 0.90 to max 2.88 ... will this low/medium/high workable in this range ? I guess I can try it right now and see the results ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to normalize the data ? I guess it is being done by WEKA classifiers.

If you want to normalize data, you have to do it. Preprocess tab - > Filters (choose) -> then find normalize and then click apply.

If you want to discretize your data, you have to follow the same process.

> You might have better luck with discretising the prediction e.g. into low/medium/high yield.

You need to normalize or discretize- this cannot be said based on your data or on your single run. For instance, discretization brings in better result for naive baye's classifiers. For SVM- not sure.

I did not see your Precision, Recall or F-score from your data. But as you are saying you have bad results on test set, then it is very possible that your classifier is experiencing overfitting. Try to increase training instances (36 is too less I guess). Keep us posting what is happening when you increase training instances.

Comment: I am using SMOReg and MultiLayer Preceptron classifiers and Linear Regression for the prediction task. I am getting the option of Normalize the attributes in MLP and use Normalize filter in SMOReg. I guess I will have to use filter explicitly for Linear Regression ? Also I would like to know is there any method to get the test data (in arff file ) to get normalized in WEKA or we have to do it separately ?

Comment: I think you should normalize your data when you use LR as well if your data range varies that much. Do you need to do normalization or not- I cannot tell that without seeing the data; I mean it all depends on data. And yes, you can normalize your data in Weka Explorer on the preprocess tab select filter and then you will find tree structured options. There you will find NORMALIZE. And upon selecting it, click on the window where NORMALIZE -PARAMETERS are and then you will have plenty of options- ways you can perform normalization on your data.